# Casting JSON array to a struct model swift

Tags: swift

I am parsing a json array of object into a model which works. In this object, there is an array to a value and I created  another model to handle that array but when ever I pass this object, the internal array returns nil after casting as the model class. Any help is appreciated

**JSON Sample**

```
[
    {
        "code": "AF",
        "code3": "AFG",
        "dial_code": "+93",
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "capital": "Kabul",
        "region": "Asia",
        "subregion": "Southern Asia",
        "states": [
            {
                "code": "BDS",
                "name": "Badakhshān",
                "subdivision": null
            },
            {
                "code": "BGL",
                "name": "Baghlān",
                "subdivision": null
            }
        ]
    }
 }

]
```

**MODEL**

```
public struct LocaleInfo {

    public var locale: Locale?

    public var id: String? {
        return locale?.identifier
    }

    public var country: String
    public var code: String
//    public var phoneCode: String
    public var states: [LocalStateInfo]

    public var flag: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "Countries.bundle/Images/\(code.uppercased())", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)
    }

    public var currencyCode: String? {
        return locale?.currencyCode
    }

    public var currencySymbol: String? {
        return locale?.currencySymbol
    }

    public var currencyName: String? {
        guard let currencyCode = currencyCode else { return nil }
        return locale?.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: currencyCode)
    }

    init(country: String, code: String/*, phoneCode: String*/, states: [LocalStateInfo]) {
        self.country = country
        self.code = code
        self.states = states
        self.locale = Locale.availableIdentifiers.map { Locale(identifier: $0) }.first(where: { $0.regionCode == code })
    }
}

public struct LocalStateInfo {
     public var code: String
     public var name: String
     public var subdivision: String
}
```

Passing the JSON Body

```
func getInfo(completionHandler: @escaping (FetchResults) -> ()) {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: LocalePickerViewController.self)
        let path = "Countries.bundle/Data/CountryCodes"

        guard let jsonPath = bundle.path(forResource: path, ofType: "json"),
            let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: jsonPath)) else {
                let error: (title: String?, message: String?) = (title: "ContryCodes Error", message: "No ContryCodes Bundle Access")
                return completionHandler(FetchResults.error(error: error))
        }

        if let jsonObjects = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) as? Array<Any> {
            var result: [LocaleInfo] = []
            for jsonObject in jsonObjects {
                guard let countryObj = jsonObject as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { continue }
                guard let country = countryObj["name"] as? String,
                    let code = countryObj["code"] as? String/*,
                    let phoneCode = countryObj["dial_code"] as? String*/ else {
                        fatalError("Broken here")
                        continue
                }
                log("countryObj state \(countryObj["states"] as? [LocalStateInfo])", .fuck)
                log("countryObj \(countryObj)", .fuck)

                let states = countryObj["states"] as? [LocalStateInfo] ?? [LocalStateInfo]()
                let new = LocaleInfo(country: country, code: code/*, phoneCode: phoneCode*/, states: states)
                result.append(new)
            }
            return completionHandler(FetchResults.success(response: result))
        }

        let error: (title: String?, message: String?) = (title: "JSON Error", message: "Couldn't parse json to Info")
        return completionHandler(FetchResults.error(error: error))
    }
```

Comment: In the past you asked a few questions about `Codable`. Why don’t you use it?

Comment: It would involve me altering the entire scope of the library which I am working on

Comment: `return completionHandler(...)`? I didn't see a `return` on your function declaration. Did I miss some part of your code?

Comment: no @Larme you did not

Comment: `let states = countryObj["states"] as? [LocalStateInfo]`. That will fail. `countryObj["states"]` is a `[[String: Any]]`, clearly not a `LocalStateInfo`. **Don't cast**, do the `init`, like you did `let new = LocaleInfo(country:...)`. Ask you this, why did you do a `LocaleInfo(country:...)`, and the why did you do `as? LocalStateInfo`? It was on the same "current logic", and yet, two different course of actions, why?

Comment: Try https://app.quicktype.io, you can just copy paste your JSON there and it will automatically generate the model for you. Also it will show you at the top how to easily decode it using JSONDecoder.

Comment: I know @Sh_Khan. Read previous comment. I do not want to completly alter the Library I am working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let states = countryObj["states"] as? [LocalStateInfo] ?? [LocalStateInfo]()
```

is presumably the line that isn't working for you. But `countryObj` is just a dictionary straight from JSON:

```
guard let countryObj = jsonObject as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { continue }
```

Why would casting it to an array of `LocalStateInfo` work at at all? It's an array of dictionaries, and you need to parse each one out individually.

You've said using `Codable` would alter the "entire scope" of the library, I don't understand how this is the case. You can implement codable (or even just `Decodable`) without affecting any other file.